# Fragment || onConfigurationChanged || Duplicate

Tags: android, fragment

I have problems with fragment when the screen orientation changes.
In my code, I have create different layout xml according to the screen orientation.
For example, I have header_landscape.xml and header_portrait.xml in the layout directory. And each different header has the same fragment in the linear layout. So when I turn my device, I have the error "duplicate id ..." that corresponding to my fragment.

The differences between layout is the content.When I am in "landscape" I display more informations than I am in "portrait".

On create of my activity :

```
 setContentView(R.layout.main_landscape); 

                //header
                date=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.headerLandscapeDate);
                routeSens=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.headerLandscapeRouteSens);
                pkHeader=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.headerLandscapePk);

                //Récupération de la listview créée dans le fichier main.xml
                maListViewPerso = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListeChoix);      

                //On attribut à notre listView l'adapter que l'on vient de créer
                maListViewPerso.setAdapter(chargeMenu());
```

$ The code of the modification of layout when the orientation screen changes.

```
 public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
 {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);


        // Checks the orientation of the screen
        if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE && isLoaded && oldScreenStateOrientation!=newConfig.orientation)
        {

            setContentView(R.layout.main_landscape);

            //header
            date=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.headerLandscapeDate);
            routeSens=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.headerLandscapeRouteSens);
            pkHeader=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.headerLandscapePk);

            maListViewPerso = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListeChoix);  
            //On attribut à notre listView l'adapter que l'on vient de créer
            maListViewPerso.setAdapter(chargeMenu());
        } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT && isLoaded && oldScreenStateOrientation!=newConfig.orientation)
        {

            setContentView(R.layout.main_portrait);


            routeSens=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.headerPortraitRouteSens);
            pkHeader=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.headerPortraitPk);

            maListViewPerso = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListeChoix);  
            //On attribut à notre listView l'adapter que l'on vient de créer
            maListViewPerso.setAdapter(chargeMenu());
        }
      }
```

If anyone have a solution.
I developp with the api8 (compatibility library fragment).

Sorry for my english.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should let android do all that configuration switching for you! Don't do anything in "onConfigurationChanged", remove all configuration changes from your manifest even!

Put your portrait layout in
**layout/ folder**

and put your landscape layout in
**layout-land/ folder**

Make sure they are both named: *main.xml* (or anything, as long as it is the same)

Then in your *activity.onCreate*, do something like this:

```
    // Will automatically select the correct layout
    setContentView(R.layout.main); 

    //header
    // If this is in portrait, date will be null. Check for that later
    date=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.headerDate);
    routeSens=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.headerRouteSens);
    pkHeader=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.headerPk);

    //Récupération de la listview créée dans le fichier main.xml
    maListViewPerso = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListeChoix);      

    //On attribut à notre listView l'adapter que l'on vient de créer
    maListViewPerso.setAdapter(chargeMenu());
```

This way, you can let android worry about which configuration to use. If you only want to display the landscape view on large screens, you could put it in a folder such as **layout-w1024dp**. This way you can have multiple layouts very easily.

Comment: Did you mean that I must duplicate all layout and create 2 folders layout (layout-land and layout-port? but the fragment appears in two differents layout? Thanks for helping.

Comment: I have tried our solution, but my header is the same in "portrait" and "landscape", how can I change this ?

Comment: It's work well, but the activity should restart and I lost my configuration. So I should save datas and object, is there a way to restore all data ?

Comment: You put your portrait layout in /layout/ and your landscape layout in /layout-land/. They can be completely different, just need the same name.

To save and restore data, save your data in onSaveInstanceState and restore it in in onCreate when the Bundle != null

Answer (score 3):

If you need to handle orientation change yourself for some reason, a solution is to remove the fragment before calling setContentView(). Here is the code that worked in my case:

```
    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(final Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // We must remove the fragment, otherwise we get a duplicate ID error when the
        // onCreateView() method is executed.
            final FragmentManager fm = this.getSupportFragmentManager();
        ExtrasFragment ef = (ExtrasFragment) fm.findFragmentByTag(ExtrasFragment.FRAGMENT_TAG);
        if( ef != null ) {  // for small screens the fragment is not embedded in this activity
            final FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
            ft.remove(ef);
            ft.commit();
            ef = null;
            fm.executePendingTransactions();
        }
        this.setContentView(R.layout.main); // contains the ExtrasFragment
    ...
}
```